# data binding with combo box is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

why this code is not working ....

I want to binding the combo box with names coming from database table like this

```
      private void getcategories()
      {
        var category = (from categories in tgs.categories
                        select categories.category_Name).ToList();
        categoryCombobox.DataSource = category;

      }

        private void categoryCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        getcategories();
      }
```

am i doing any thing wrong for binding the details to combobox 
any suggestions pls that would be helpful to me

Comment: i dint understand what u are saying , i am using winforms....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void getcategories()
{
    var category = (from categories in tgs.categories
                        select categories.category_Name).ToList();
    categoryCombobox.DataSource = category;

    categoryCombobox.DataBind(); //dont forget this

}
```

edit - just as a small general criticism, your method is named poorly. I would do something more like:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Getcategories()
{
    return categproes.Select(c=>c.category_Name);
}

private void BindCategories()
{
    categoryCombobox.DataSource = this.GetCategories();
    categoryCombobox.DataBind();
}

private void categoryCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindCategories();
}
```

Comment: i am not able to find the property categorycombobox.databind()  it will shows this option  categorycombobox.databinds

Comment: As commented he is on winform

Comment: It's been to long since I've done winforms, there is no .DataBind() call?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a certain column to be bind in combo box.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that `category_name` is a string, so that wouldn't be necessary. If it's not a string, but a complex type then you absolutely would be required to specify the name of the property to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding it in the Selected Index changed event of the same combobox, which will not fire unless you have some items in the combobox.

Try the code in getcategories() somewhere else like form_load or on a button click and remove it from the handler

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to set the datasource *every* time the index changes, just the once in the `FormLoad`, event for example. Otherwise it will never be initially set, and may cause an infinite loop when the index does change, as it will reset the datasource, changing the index, which will reset the datasource etc..

Try changing it to this:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadCategoriesCombo();
}

private void LoadCategoriesCombo()
{
    var category = (from categories in tgs.categories
                    elect categories.category_Name).ToList();

    categoryCombobox.DataSource = category;   
}
```